# Getting the difference between two time/dates using php?

Tags: php

I am wanting to find out the time difference in minutes between two dates which is in the format d-m-Y H:i (14-04-2009 12:15) using php?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Parse the times into timestamps using strtotime() and then simply subtract one from the other.

After that you can get the number of minutes, days and so on by using math functions.

For example:

```
// $date1 and $date2 are given
// the difference is in seconds
$difference = strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2);

// getting the difference in minutes
$difference_in_minutes = $difference / 60;
```

**Reference:** [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: PHP may assume your date is in m-d-Y format when the numbers for month and day make the format ambiguous (the example you give is unambiguous, as there are not 14 months). You may need to parse and swap the day and month.

Comment: Of course, I didn't recognize that the given date is not in standard US-english format.

Comment: Exactly. strtotime might give you unexpected results since the date format you're using is unusual.

Comment: `strtotime()` assumes European / Australian format (dd-mm-yyyy) when the separators are hyphens. Forward-slashes make it use US format (mm-dd-yyyy)

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$currentDateTime = date('m/d/Y H:i:s');
$model_current_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 
strtotime($currentDateTime));
echo $model_current_time."------";

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s A', 
$row['model_creation_time']);//get from resouses
$new_date_format = $date->format('m/d/Y H:i:s');
$model_creation_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 
strtotime($new_date_format));
echo $model_creation_time;

$datetime1 = new DateTime($model_current_time);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($model_creation_time);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->d;
echo $interval->h;
echo $interval->s;
```