# php: DateTime::diff() on 5.2

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What can use for DateTime::diff() for PHP 5.2 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033224/what-can-use-for-datetimediff-for-php-5-2)
>   [Getting the difference between two time/dates using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770564/getting-the-difference-between-two-time-dates-using-php)

Hi,

i have use this function: DateTime::diff()

but this function work only with 5.3.

Maybe somebody have the same function who work with 5.2?

Thanks

Comment: Have you searched here? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+time+difference

Comment: This was asked just 2 weeks ago: [What can use for DateTime::diff() for PHP 5.2 ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033224/what-can-use-for-datetimediff-for-php-5-2)

Comment: @Felix  that one is asking for timestamp based comparison, not `DateTime`

Comment: @Pekka: Mmh maybe I don't understand, but what is the difference? `DateTime::diff()` is to get the difference between two dates right? What is the difference to the question I linked to? (or is it that the search should be `php+date+difference`?)

Comment: @Felix the `DateTime` class has a different storage format from UNIX timestamps. `DateTime` dates can go beyond 1970 and 2038, so timestamp based comparison may break

Answer (score 1):

The user contributed notes to `date_diff()` (always look there first, there's usually something there) [offer an alternative](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#97810).

I've not used it myself but it looks okay. It uses timestamps for comparison, so you won't be able to handle dates < 1970 or > 2038 with it.