# Date difference between two date variables with AM PM format.

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the difference between two time/dates using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770564/getting-the-difference-between-two-time-dates-using-php)

I have two dates variable
let $arrival_time="7.30 AM";
    $departure_time="8.30 PM";

Then how can I calculate the time difference between these two variables in php ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php   
$arrival_time="7.30 AM";
$departure_time="8.30 PM";

$d1=  strtotime($arrival_time);
$d2=  strtotime($departure_time);

$diff=$d2-$d1;

//Print the difference in hours : minutes
echo date("H:i",$diff);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$am = "7:30AM";
$pm = "8:30PM";
$minutes_diff = round(abs(strtotime($pm) - strtotime($am)) / 60);
```